# numerical time differentiation in GNURadio

Tags: phase, gnuradio, software-defined-radio, frequency-modulation

I'm hoping to put together a cheap modulation monitor for wideband FM radio using an rtl sdr usb, on the FCC website, it's listed that the modulation percentage for an FM station is the actual frequency deviation over the [max allowable](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-47/chapter-I/subchapter-C/part-73/subpart-B/section-73.310) frequency deviation expressed as a percentage.  I was hoping to avoid using the bessel null method so I could make something that could monitor the modulation percentage in real time and I found a [presentation online](https://www.montana.edu/aolson/eele445/lecture_notes/EELE44514_L30-32.pdf) that gave this formula:
[image: PeakFrequencyDeviation]

With gnuradio, I think I was able to get the phase out of a radio signal:
[image]
With this setup:
[image]

I'm not sure if the phase I'm showing is the phase I need, but, I wanted to know if there was any way to take a numerical time derivative of the phase info while the program runs so I can try and find the frequency deviation using the formula for peak frequency deviation above.  If I can get this ready, I have permission to compare the modulation for a radio station measured with this setup and compare it with their modulation monitor's readings.

Comment: IIRC the quadrature demodultor block will give you an approximation of $d\phi/dt$.  It outputs $\mathrm{arg}(z[n]z^*[n-1])$ which is a good numerical approximation to the normalized phase velocity between $[-\pi, \pi]$.  You'll have to multiply the result by $Fs/2/\pi$ to get the actual frequency deviation.

Comment: it looks like you're clipping in your receiver.

Comment: yep, $\frac{\mathrm d\phi}{\mathrm dt}$ is pretty much "instantaneous frequency", i.e., what an frequency demodulator will give you.